# Problem with scroolview in Xamarin, no data is printed. It works when I retype ItemsSource (Persons) while application works

Tags: xamarin, binding

It is my xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:mojaapkamobilna="clr-namespace:MojaApkaMobilna" x:DataType="mojaapkamobilna:MainViewModel"
         x:Class="MojaApkaMobilna.MainPage">
<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="TopLabel" Text="{Binding TopText}"></Label>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label VerticalOptions="Center">Imie:</Label>
        <Entry x:Name="Name" Placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię" WidthRequest="300" Text="{Binding Name}"></Entry>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label VerticalOptions="Center">Haslo:</Label>
        <Entry x:Name="Password" Placeholder ="Wpisz swoje hasło" IsPassword="True" WidthRequest="300" Text="{Binding Password}"></Entry>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Kliknij we mnie..." Command = "{Binding OnClickCommand}"></Button>

    <ScrollView>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackLayout>
                       <Label FontSize="20"  Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Password}"></Label>
                   </StackLayout>
               </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

And it's my xaml.cs file:

```
namespace MojaApkaMobilna
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And my view model class:

```
 namespace MojaApkaMobilna
{
    internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _password;
        private string _topText;

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public string TopText
        {
            get => _topText;
            set
            {
                _topText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TopText));
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
                OnClickCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
                OnClickCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public Command OnClickCommand { get; }

        private void Button_Clicked()
        {
            TopText = "Wpisane imie: " + Name + ", Haslo: " + Password;

            try
            {
                Persons.Add(new Person(Name, Password));
                foreach (var person in Persons)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(person.Password);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Persons.Count);
            }
            catch
            {
                TopText = "Nie powiódł się zapis nowego użytkownika";
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            OnClickCommand = new Command(Button_Clicked, Validate);

        }


        /* Informowanie widoku o zmianach */
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private bool Validate() => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password);
        
    }
}
```

And my problem is that my scroolview doesnt work. Interesting is that when program is running, when I delete that ItemsSource (xaml file) and write it again, it starts working. Why is it happening and how to repair it?

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
```

I'm weak in Xamarin, so thank you for your understanding.

Comment: First, there is no reason to have a CollectionView nested in a ScrollView.   Second, `Persons` is empty when the VM is created.  Are you saying that after you click the button the CollectionView is still empty?

Comment: When I click the buttom I add a new Item to Collection Persons.

Comment: I am asking if the UI updates when you click the button?  Yes or No?

Comment: https://youtu.be/P732U2i0d_8

Comment: Have you removed the unneeded scrollview?  You may also want to either specify a height or VerticalOptions on the CollectionView

Comment: Yes I have removed.    https://youtu.be/8SaKhzAj3qc

Comment: I don't know, maybe that binding doesn't find right path to my property Persons.

Comment: I doubt it.  The likely problem is that either the CV is not allocating any space because it is empty and doesn't have any layout options assigned, or possibly Hot Reload is just causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. In **AssemblyInfo** file:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

replace by:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
```